# Get back dropped database from aws ec2 instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have my server instance on aws ec2. On which I have my database. Somehow that database was dropped. So Is there any way to get that database. And I don't have dump file.

Answer (score 0):

If your instance was using EBS for database volume and you still have the volume you just have to recreate an EC2 instance and [attach the volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html) and mount it.

If you have a snapshot of the volume you can create a new volume from the snapshot and do the same as perviously mentionned.

If you have no volume, no snapshot and no dump you are out of luck.